# Why is conditional test for ComboBox value being ignored? (Access VBA)

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-forms

I have an `If` clause that was being completely ignored, until I discovered a workaround, but now I'd like to better understand what is happening under-the-hood.

We have a form with a ComboBox that gets populated, but a default value is not set on it.  When I go to save the form, we need to test if the user selected a value.  The code was:

```
If (Me.Combo78.Value = "") Then
    mb "Please select a value"
End If
```

The code would never fire, until I changed the condition to read:

```
If ("" & Me.Combo78.Value = "") Then
    mb "Please select a value"
End If
```

I'm guessing that the `"" &` forces the comparison to be a text comparison, and therefore can validly test against the empty string `""`, but what was the previous comparison actually doing, and is there a better, more intuitive way to manage this?  The solution I have just feels gross.

-- 30 years experience with coding in Pascal, HTML, Javascript, but <1 year coding in VBA, after being handed a legacy application that needs debugging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the ComboBox has no value then `Me.Combo78.Value` will be null and consequently `Me.Combo78.Value = ""` will be null and will not validate the test expression for the `if` statement.

In your second code, concatenating an empty string with a null value will return an empty string, and so `"" & Me.Combo78.Value` returns an empty string, thus validating the test expression.

If you wish, you can verify this for yourself in the VBE Immediate Window (accessible using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>):

```vb
?Null = ""
Null
?Null & "" = ""
True
```

A more readable solution might be:

```vb
If IsNull(Me.Combo78) Or Me.Combo78 = "" Then
    mb "Please select a value"
End If
```

Alternatively, you could use the [`Nz`](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/nz-function-8ef85549-cc9c-438b-860a-7fd9f4c69b6c) function:

```vb
If Nz(Me.Combo78, "") = "" Then
    mb "Please select a value"
End If
```

Since the `Value` property is the default member for this class, it may be safely omitted.

Comment: Thank you for the very clear explanation.  I had missed that the Value field was a Variant, and therefore, undefined is Null.  Just starting to get used to VBA, and how it does the most basic of things.